# Nintendo 2DS Download Bundled and EShop titles on multiple 2DS

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I know a similar question has been asked [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/92828/can-i-transfer-individual-3ds-eshop-games) but I feel mine is different enough:
I have 3 2DS (not 3DS) all tied to the same Nintendo account. Two of the systems were bundles that included a software title. From [Nintendo's own website](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/542/~/pre-installed-software-is-missing-or-deleted-%28nintendo-3ds%29)  they say I should be able to see the games that came bundled for free in the eshop.

Is there any way to install these bundled titles on all three of my 2DS? I've seen no way to copy the games or even restore them for free it wants to charge me $30 for each system. The one it came on just shows installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done. The games are tied to that console only, and then once you register a nnid, the game becomes tied to that nnid. The only way to get the games off of one console and onto another is to do a system transfer, which will remove the nnid/account(and games) from that specific 3ds/2ds, and then register the account and everything on another system. Essentially, the only way to play those games is on the 2ds/3ds they came with, unless you register the game with an nnid and do a system transfer, but you'll no longer be able to play the game on the system you transfered it from.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed this was the answer but had hoped Nintendo had gone the same route as other big players like Sony and Xbox. It certainly makes the bundles less valuable to me since now I'll have to pay $30 for each DS to have the game I thought I already purchased. At that price, the switch would have been more appealing although with the same issue.